# Modifying decision function in LibSVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm, data-mining, libsvm

The decision function for C-support vector classification is

$sign(wT\phi(x)+b)=sgn(\sum_{i=1}^{l}y_i\alpha_iK(x_i,x)+b)$

How can I modify it to

$sgn(wT\phi(x)+b)=sgn(\sum_{i=1}^{l}y_i\alpha_iK(x_i,x)+b+aconstant)$

that aconstant is a ARBITRARY number

Comment: Could you please be more specific as to your goal? The way the question is posed now makes it hard to say what you want (e.g., what are the unknowns)

Comment: Why not let libsvm output the decision values and then add `aconstant` to those prior to thresholding manually?

Answer (score 1):

Download the source code, go to the source of the method that returns your predictions - and add your constant. Or add your constant to the bias term.

No, LibSVM doesn't provide an API for doing it for you.